Possible to create a database View in Microsoft Dynamics (Sales) 365?
Is it possible to create a database View to a Microsoft Dynamics 365 instance? I understand that Dynamics runs on Dataverse but there is a SQL Server endpoint that I'm able to connect to using SSMS. However, when I try to create a View it returns an error message that says the operation is not supported. Searching online on the topic only provides articles/videos about creating System or Personal Views using Power Apps. I don't think this is what we want as we need data from about a dozen different tables, several of them are custom. I know what tables we need and the specific joins between them so creating a traditional database View would be quite easy for me.
What we're trying to do is create a Power BI report using DirectQuery because we want to fetch the data in real-time but the performance is very poor. It was suggested that we try creating a database View and then having the PBI report call that directly.
And yes, we could switch to an import model on the PBI side which would be more performant but our environment is restricted to 1hr refresh increments at most. The current requirement for this particular report is for it to be real-time.

the TDS endpoint (the one you are using to connect using SSMS) is read only, this is the reason you cannot create sql views

@GuidoPreite okay, that makes sense. Do you think I would be able to create a linked server connection to it from another SQL Server instance? If so, then I should be able to create a traditional database View on the linked server.

I don't know if you can create a linked server, because usually to move/sync data from a dataverse instance or you use synapse or Azure Data Factory or an integrator like SSIS with KingswaySoft, really depends on the size of the tables you need to sync

@Brad did you consider exposing Dataverse data to Power BI using TDS endpoint to create and save your queries there. I am not a Power BI dev but I think it could be a possible workaround for you.

@KhadimAli yes, this does work but it just imports the data into Power BI. This would usually be okay under normal circumstances, however we want the specific report we're creating to pull the data from Dynamics at runtime. We've made some tweaks to our original DirectQuery and it seems to be performing better now.
